# The learning_rate in TensorFlow code is the sum learning rate of a batch or the learning rate of a data?

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch

```
import tensorflow as tf
batch_size = 10
learning_rate = 0.001
tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate)
```

So the question is:

The `learning_rate` of a data is 0.0001 or 0.001 ?

The sum `learning_rate` of a batch is 0.01 or 0.001 ?

Answer (score 0):

It is the learning rate that you set on the optimizer for your problem. It requires a fair bit of experimentation to figure out what learning rate works best for your problem. It is a more of an art than a science, though there exists heuristics on an optimal range of values to select from.

For most problems, the default learning rate should be a good starting point.

Comment: The real question I want to solve is the multi-gpu training problem.

Comment: Perhaps you should describe the multi GPU training problem in the question